# How can I handle date/time stamps and compare with day offset?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

I'm having some issues when handling date/time stamps within Rust. The first issue is the type of date/time stamp which (I believe) is ISO 8601 zero meridean w/ local time zone offset. Here's the format: `"2023-09-09T10:24:10.239000-07:00"` which comes from Jira's REST API ie its creation date. Outside of struggles with chrono handling that date, I've actually tried speedate which has been quite faster... however, I'm struggling to figure out a way to calculate a datetime which is 30 days in the past, to determine whether or not something is over 30 days old.

I've tried using speedate:

```
let test_parser = DateTime::parse_str(serde_json::from_str(&creation_date).unwrap());
```

Which was quite a bit faster in handling. Although, I couldn't figure out a way to subtract or handle calculating a date that was 30 days from today, and then comparing test_parser to 30daysago to determine whether or not something is older than 30 days.

I did find a chrono function which could do something similar which was using `chrono::Duration::days(-30)` however, I couldn't compare duration to datetime, and I had challenges getting Chrono to parse that datetime, in comparison to speedate which parsed it well.

Comment: how about `Local::now` https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/struct.Local.html#method.now

Comment: speedate also has `DateTime::now` https://docs.rs/speedate/latest/speedate/struct.DateTime.html#method.now

Comment: The issue isn't getting the datetime for now, it's offsetting 30 days and comparing to creation_date

Comment: I'm unable to add or subtract `Duration::days(-30)` from speedate::DateTime type and i'm having difficulties with chrono parsing that specific datetime format. The error i get is "invalid" having tried from many times: parse_from_rfc3339, parse_from_rfc2822, parse_from_str

Comment: Well the string you wrote works, so I dunno what issues you're having. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5272d9862387e7c49623f0d2b4101d4f

Comment: It appears it changes depending on what is parsing it... if it's speedate, then it's `2023-09-09T10:24:10.239000-07:00` however, if it's chrono::DateTime then it's `2023-09-09T10:24:10.239-0700`... that's interesting...... i checked the raw output, and it's the "chrono version".. it appears as if speedate adds the extra bits to make it valid... but in its raw form, chrono determines it to be invalid.

Comment: You can always specify the exact format specifier yourself. `chrono` is very flexible.

Comment: Can you give an example of string that is not parsed well with `chrono`?

Comment: Yes, that would be `2023-09-09T10:24:10.239-0700`... so `let time = DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339("2023-09-09T10:24:10.239-0700").unwrap();`

Comment: You can use a custom format then, `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.f%z`.

Comment: That works, and figured it out.. looks like i also needed to unwrap it before comparison. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom format in `chrono` to parse your datetime: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.f%z`.

For example, to compare to 30 days ago:

```rust
fn main() {
    let time = "2023-09-09T10:24:10.239-0700";
    let time = chrono::DateTime::parse_from_str(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.f%z").unwrap();
    let timenow = chrono::Local::now();
    let offset = timenow - chrono::Duration::days(30);
    dbg!(time.cmp(&offset.fixed_offset()));
}
```